# Arrows not showing up in airbnb/react-dates (yes in mobile screen, not in desktop)

Tags: react-dates

I am using the library airbnb/react-dates for the datepicker. I am using the standard code:

```
<SingleDatePicker
  orientation={datePickerOrientation}
  date={newEndsOn}
  onDateChange={(date) => setNewEndsOn(date)}
  focused={datePickerFocused}
  onFocusChange={({ focused }) => setDatePickerFocused(focused)}
/>
```

where `datePickerOrientation` can get the values 'vertical' or 'horizontal', depending on mobile device or desktop.

In mobile device I can see the navigation arrows to move over months. Unfortunately, I can not see the arrows on the desktop version.

Does anybody know why? Is this expected behaviour?

I found in this issue that you can override the arrows, but unfortunately it just work for mobile:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/692

Somehow the arrows for desktop are not in the dom.

Comment: could you please provide the implementation of `datePickerOrientation ` function

Comment: could you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166112/react-dates-responsive-datepangepicker