# react-dates responsive daterangepicker

Tags: reactjs, daterangepicker, react-dates

I am using a react-dates plugin from Airbnb in one of my projects. I am using daterangepicker default calendar props like this one http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?path=/story/drp-calendar-props--default. But this is not responsive in smaller devices from tab to mobile. I want to make some changes here in the tab and mobile view like it would appear as a vertical calendar as this http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?path=/story/drp-calendar-props--vertical. I want to achieve this using the given props in the docs and make changes in CSS using media queries.
This is my implementation so far:

```
<DateRangePicker
      startDate={startDate}
      startDateId="startDate"
      endDate={endDate}
      endDateId="startDate"
      customInputIcon={customInputIcon}
      onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
      focusedInput={focusedInput}
      onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
      hideKeyboardShortcutsPanel={hideKeyboardShortcutsPanel}
      appendToBody={true}
      navPrev={navPrev}
      navNext={navNext}
      isOutsideRange={this.isOutsideRange}
    />
```

which looks like this
[image]
I want to achieve a view like this in tab and mobile devices
[image]

But not sure about how to do the implementation in this case of responsiveness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding `orientation` prop

To differentiate it based on responsiveness, you can do

`const orientation = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal'`

`<DateRangePickerWrapper orientation={orientation} autoFocus />`

Comment: but using this props always makes the calendar vertical but I want it horizontal in Desktop views and vertical in tab and mobile views

Comment: @ashfaqrafi Updated comment above.

Comment: could you please answer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537302/open-a-specific-tab-by-matching-the-browser-url-and-tab-url. Thank you